# What does this circle look like?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been given an integral to evaluate over a circle $$|z-i|=3$$

I am trying to work out what this circle looks like.
Is the radius of the circle $3$ centred on the origin?

Comment: Radius of $3$ centered on $i$. Writing $z = x + yi$, then

$$|z - i| = \sqrt{ x^2 + (y-1)^2} = 3$$

Comment: You mean i=1 right?

Comment: No. $i$ is a constant that cannot be set equal to another. I mean that if the center is at $z_{center} = a + bi$, then $a = 0$ and $b = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of all points $z \in \mathbb{C}$ that satisfy $|z-a| = r$, for $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $r \geq 0,$ form a circle centered at $a$ of radius $r.$ Note that $|z-a|$ is just the distance between $z$ and $a$; therefore the equation $|z-a| = r$ means that we're considering all the points $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the distance between $z$ and $a$ is $r.$ This gives precisely the aforementioned circle.

Comment: ok, so if I have an integral $\int \frac{z}{z+2}dz$ then looking at the denominator, I know it has a pole at $-2$. so because $2<3$, I can say that the function $\frac{z}{z+2} $ is not analytical on the circle $|z-i|=3$. Is this correct?

Comment: The pole is at $z = -2$, not $z = 2$. That pole is in the interior of the circle as the distance from $i$ to $-2$ is $|-2-i| = \sqrt 5 < 3$.

Comment: And, continuing the previous thought, you have that the function is analytic on the circle, since it is holomorphic on the interior of the (open) set where $\sqrt{6} < |z-i|$, which contains the circle.

Answer (score 0):

In case of complex numbers, $x$ axis is termed as real axis and $y$ axis is termed as imaginary axis.
$$
|z-i|=3
$$
Take $z=x+iy$
$$
|x+iy-1|=3
$$
$$
\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}=3
$$
$$
x^2+(y-1)^2=9
$$